# What are our best Q&As to show off this site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I'm looking to promote this site and want to hear from our domain experts what our best questions in each discipline are.  I'm interested in both questions with great answers and also great questions in need of answers.  Overall, quality is what I'm looking for to entice more people to visit and contribute.

Why am I asking here?  I can pick out some great meteorology questions but distinguishing good from great outside of my expertise is a bit harder to do.  I realize "great" is a bit subjective, so really I'm just asking for questions that you think show off this site within your domain of expertise.

Comment: Note this is a community wiki to facilitate keeping a single answer with additions from everyone.

Comment: Perhaps, as a starting point, look at the highest voted examples for each tag.

Comment: In narrower subjects (and by that i mean subjects with less questions on the site), it becomes difficult to pick *objectively* a great Q&A I have to admit. I for one have either asked or answered two thirds of the [tag:paleontology] and half the [tag:paleoclimatology] questions for instance.

Comment: Highest voted might mean a question is accessible/understandable for many people coming in through the Hot Questions list, not necessarily that a question is good and interesting for domain experts.

Comment: I agree with gerrit. Only domain experts can identify what is a good and interesting question.

Comment: Maybe you should go ahead and write an answer with the Q&A in meteorology you think are great, and we can complete it with others in other domains.

Comment: @casey This question first needs to describe: what is the intended audience of this site to "show off" to? See the comments about *domain experts* and *accessible/understandable for many people*. Will a (any) domain expert evaluate questions with emphasis on accessability, factual correctness, depth of the answers, etc? If the audience is clear, please [edit] that into your question.